# How does Googlebot crawl a webpage?

Tags: googlebot, web-crawlers

Today I had a silly fight with my colleague. My friend told me, "Googlebot crawls a web page only through the links present in webpage or through the number of page views (by text ads)."  But I argued, "Googlebot can crawl the webpage even if we don't submit a *sitemap.xml* in Google Webmaster Tools or don't have any links in the page. That is, Googlebot can crawl the page without any external force, it would automatically visit the page and crawl it."

What's the exact answer? Please inform me of any other factors involved.

Comment: Sathiya, you may want to read this introduction: http://ligatures.net/content/expertise/web-crawling.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Sitemap Confusion*

Many people believe that a sitemap is required for the site to be discovered this is not true, a sitemap's purpose to help Google ensure that the crawling of data is done correctly. Google has many discovery methods that expends further than just a sitemap.

*DNS Collective*

When a new domain is registered these records are obtainable though DNS servers, Google even owns its own DNS servers via 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4 which is a public DNS service, new domains will surely be added to these automatically and while I can't find official response on this I'm dead certain that they are sure to have something in place.

*Unstoppable Text References and Backlinks*

Often newly registered domains will appear on lists all over the world, even some sites publish whois data whenever anyone does a whois on the domain.. It saves it to a page for example and then crawls for more data.

*Deep Pages*

These can't be detected unless there is some reference to them, this includes text mentions, link mentions.

Comment: thank you for your answer but my question is not about domain and its about other webpages..

Comment: Added to answer, without a backlink, on page link, or sitemap Google will not be able to discover the page.

Comment: @bybe: to your comment, I answer it's not 100% sure, it's theoretical as I mentioned in a comment of my answer. In practice, Googlebot can try to follow a text representing a link found in a webpage (not a link with `<a>` tag, just text).

Comment: Google does read links in raw format, this has been proven several times with people using the referrer trick using logs for text backlinks.. You know sites that stupidly have their logs viewable online when people use referrers on them to gain back links in text form - its vary common.

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't guarantee to crawl your website. So it is a dice roll with waiting on Googlebot to crawl, let alone index your website. You should setup a **sitemap.xml** file in Google Webmaster Tools -- your website will be indexed much faster as you are making it known to Google that your website exists.

Without links from other webpages to your website, Googlebot may never find your page and crawl it.

Stick with a **sitemap.xml** file and tell Google about your site.

Answer (score 2):

*Sitemap.xml* helps indexing a website by specifying to Googlebot to crawl your website but if a website doesn't have a *sitemap.xml*, of course Googlebot can crawl it.

Googlebot follow links on internet and if it finds a *dofollow* link to one of your webpage, it follows it and crawl your webpage (and maybe your website).

Comment: So you are saying that without any link or site map Google bot won't crawl that page.. right?

Comment: If i have a fresh page which don't have any incoming backlink and sitemap don't have that page's link means Google bot how crawl that page?

Comment: @John Sanjay: If you don't submit _sitemap.xml_ to Google Webmaster Tools and your webpage don't have incoming links, Google theoretically can't find your webpage.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but it does happen.  I'm not sure how, but I've seen Google discover pages that I know have no links to and are not in any sitemaps. Theory's for other means of discovery are Google analytics's codes, data from chrome browser, amongst other things.

Comment: @moobot: I would be interested by a link that proves your saying, any to share?

Comment: @Zistoloen: No none at the moment. I might throw up a test URL and see what happens. If I do, I'll keep you informed.